# Show association errors in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a model: review.rb

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :presence => true
  belongs_to :product
end
```

model: product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true

  has_many :reviews, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and this form: _form.html.haml

```
=form_for([@product, @product.reviews.build]) do |f|
  .field
    =f.label :title
    %br
    =f.text_field :title
```

with this reviews_controller:

```
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @review = @product.reviews.create(params[:review])
  redirect_to product_path(@product)
end
```

When I add a review with no title the review doesn't get created because the title is required (which is good). I'm not sure how to get the errors to show on this association though.

I tried this:

```
=form_for([@product, @product.reviews.build]) do |f|
  -if @product.reviews.errors.any?
    .errors
      %h2
        =pluralize(@product.reviews.errors.count, "error")
      %ul
        =@product.reviews.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li
            =msg
```

but got this error:

```
undefined method `errors' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000103e31df0>
```

I tried this:

```
  -if @review.errors.any?
    .errors
      %h2
        =pluralize(@review.errors.count, "error")
      %ul
        =@review.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li
            =msg
```

And got:

```
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
```

In the controller when I:

```
    raise @review.errors.inspect
```

I can see the errors:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000103d88c28 @base=#<Review id: nil, title: "", description: "", rating: nil, helpful: nil, product_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:title=>["can't be blank", "is too short (minimum is 5 characters)"]}>
```

What am I forgetting? How do I get the errors to show?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you make the call to `redirect_to product_path(@product)`, you are invoking a different controller action, namely the `Products#show` action. The instance variables your views will have been reset. You probably aren't initializing a `@review` instance variable in this action which is why you are getting an exception.

What you want is something like this

```
# posts_controller.rb
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @review = @product.reviews.build
end

# show.html.erb
= form_for([@product, @review]) do |f|
  -if @review.errors.any?
    .errors
      %h2
        =pluralize(@review.errors.count, "error")
      %ul
        =@review.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li
            =msg

# reviews_controller.rb
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @review = @product.reviews.build(params[:review])
  if @review.save
    redirect_to product_path(@product)
  else
    render 'products/show'
  end
end
```

The key is that if the `review` is unsuccessfully created, you will re-render the page with the same instance variables intact.

Comment: this doesn't seem to add the associated @review model to the @product. i don't think just calling save on @review will save it to @product. `@product.reviews << @review` should do the trick, no? is there something better?

Comment: The call to ```@product.reviews.build(...)``` should do just that. Specifically, it will set the @review model's product_id to that of the @product.

Comment: You can not use the errors method in the association "reviews", the error method can be only used for a single object, like @product.

Comment: I updated the code snippet to the 2nd version from the OP which used a single `@review` instance variable for the errors. Thanks for pointing that out @VictorHazbunAnuff